# Shuffle a MySQL row in a PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am doing this in PHP:

```
function populateQuestions(){
     global $dbc;
     $query = "SELECT * FROM Questions";

     $result = $dbc->getAll($query);
     shuffle($result);
     return $result;
}
```

The above snippet shuffles the questions that my user sees, so he sees random questions every time.

However my SQL table has answerA,answerB,answerC,answerD as possible answer fields.
answerA is always correct.

I would like to shuffle these 4 fields ONLY before I json_decode them.

So answerA might be answer B, answer C might be answer A etc etc...

Is that possible to do?

> My table structure for table Questions:
>
> **ID -    name -  image - answerA - answerB - answerC - answerD - category**

Comment: Post your table structure. And post an example data you getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT id, answer FROM(
    SELECT id, answerA as answer FROM Question UNION ALL
    SELECT id, answerB FROM Question UNION ALL
    SELECT id, answerC FROM Question UNION ALL
    SELECT id, answerD FROM Question)
ORDER BY id, RAND();
```

Comment: I would like to return back a single array with all the results but just the 4 answer rows shuffled. If I use the above snippet I will have to use 2 PHP arrays, one with the question names, categories etc and one with the answers. How can I use your example in my snippet above and return back a single array with just the answers shuffled?

Comment: It is actually not possible. You can random row, not column.

Answer (score 0):

When you display the data, just shufle an array and print the questions based on that array:

```
$answerOrder = shuffle(array('answerA', 'answerB', 'answerC', 'answerD'));
foreach($answerOrder as $columnName) {
    echo $questions[$currentId][$columnName]
}
```

Assuming that the $questions array is the return value of the populateQuestions() and you iterate throught it. In the iteration the $currentId is the `key` from the $questions array.

The $questions[$currentId] contains a row from the db.

With this solution, you do not add extra in the DB and you can track the correct answers position while you are displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

This is but a simple approach to how I interpreted your question.

```
<?php
    function populateQuestions(){
        //global $dbc;
        //$query = "SELECT * FROM Questions";
        // I'm assuming that your array from the database looks like the one represented by $result.
        $result = array(array('ID'=>'1', 'name'=>'Question One', 'image'=>'1.jpg', 'answerA'=>'ans1', 'answerB'=>'ans2', 'answerC'=>'ans3', 'answerD'=>'ans4', 'category'=>'quiz'), array('ID'=>'2', 'name'=>'Question Two', 'image'=>'2.jpg', 'answerA'=>'ans5', 'answerB'=>'ans6', 'answerC'=>'ans7', 'answerD'=>'ans8', 'category'=>'quiz')); /// sample database results array
        $temporaryArray = array();
        foreach($result as $key=>$value){
            $letters = range('A', 'D');
            shuffle($letters);
            $temporaryArray[$key]['answer'.$letters[0]] = $value['answerA'];
            $temporaryArray[$key]['answer'.$letters[1]] = $value['answerB'];
            $temporaryArray[$key]['answer'.$letters[2]] = $value['answerC'];
            $temporaryArray[$key]['answer'.$letters[3]] = $value['answerD'];
        }
        shuffle($temporaryArray);
        return $temporaryArray;
    }
?>
```